# VS Code Python extenstion auto-import imports hook instead of src.hook

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentaly clicked a message that I want to `add src to path` or something pretty similar and after this action everytime when I there is an auto-import of a module it imports the module but without src (in my example).

Example:

dir: `src/`

file: `hook.py`

function: `send_message_via_webhook`

When I start to type `send` - auto-import sees `send_message_via_webhook` which is fine BUT the path is `from hook import send_message_via_webhook` instead of `from src.hook import send_message_via_webhook`.

Can anyone please help me? It's driving me crazy and I can't find anything to help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First, you need to figure out if its an extension or the editor. To do this, start your editor without any extensions installed, then check if the issue persists. If it does still exist let me know. If it doesn't exist, enable extensions one at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: @JAY-DEV hello! Thanks a lot for replying. So I disabled all the eextensions and found out that the `Python` extension is the issue. (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) to be exact. Reinstalling the extenstion did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found the issue. I made 2 changes. First I deleted the added item in `Python › Analysis: Extra Paths` - there was `src` that I (probably) added. And then I unchecked `Python › Analysis: Auto Search Paths`. That made the difference.